# How to convert dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm to millisecond in Angular 6

Tags: date, angular6, milliseconds

I want to convert a date which is in dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm format to millisecond.

```
this.startDate = 02-12-2019 13:15;
```

that is 2nd dec 2019.

How to convert that to millisecond.
Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Milliseconds as in a JavaScript date-friendly Unix timestamp?

Comment: yes ..@ceejayoz

Comment: You'll probably have to parse your date/time format into a Date object. It's a non-standard format so it's going to take some work on your end.

Answer (score 0):

Date cannot be converted to millisecond but you can get millisecond by using `getTime()`

```
yourTime.getTime();
```

This is a plain javascript function which will give you the time out of date. In case you want to display date in specific format you can use date pipe and I hope i=you know that

```
{{ yourDate | date: 'mediumTime' }}
```

Comment: yes i want to get millisecond. when i am doing like this  (new Date(data.startDate)).getTime()); it is returning one millisecond . but when i am taking that millisecond and trying to get date from that it is showing me date as month and month as date

Comment: suppose this is my date 01-12-2020 00:00 that is 1st dec 2020.
when i am converting like this (new Date(data.startDate)).getTime()); , it is giving me 1578767400000. but when i am again trying to check the date here https://www.timecalculator.net/milliseconds-to-date. it is showing Sun 12 January 2020
00:00:00

Comment: I think the date is taking as US date format, you can convert your date format to USA format and then convert that to time. like USA date format is `mm-dd-yyyy` but india/uk date format is `dd-mm-yy`